# Wildcard subscribe not working as expected

Tags: javascript, pubnub

Using the JS SDK v3.7.14, and simply placing the example code at [this doc](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#subscribe_example_wildcard) (which by the way has a typo in the error callback, no `r` variable declared) into my app for testing. Then, publishing to `ab.channel`, no message is received by the subscribed callback.

I have Data Stream Controller enabled as well as the Access Manager. I'm not getting any errors or 403's from any error callbacks, so I am to assume its not a PAM issue.

I grant the the user R/W access to `ab.*` and the 'subscribe' connects fine, and the 'publish' callback returns a 'sent' obj, the message published to a sub-channel is not received however.

Comment: Good question.  You need to have this enabled as a spacial flag inside the stream controller configuration.

Comment: Try to fist disable Stream Controller, then re-enable Stream Controller in your account to activate.

Comment: doman412 - send details to support@pubnub.com including your sub-key. We can engage privately without exposing your secure information and we will reply with formal answer here.

Comment: To address the ```r``` variable issue, that is a typo. The argument is declared as ```e``` and that is what would be in the ```stringify``` method. Thanks for reporting this. We will update that soon.

Comment: The bug in the docs code has been updated. Thanks again for reporting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Enabling Wildcard Subscribe in the PubNub Stream Controller Add-On

You can enable Wildcard Subscribe by going into your PubNub Dashboard account:

1. Select the appropriate App & Key
2. Scroll down to the Stream Controller add-on
3. If not already enabled, click the Add button
4. Click the Configure button
5. Click the Enable Wildcard Subscribe checkbox

### Some quick highlights

- Once wildcard subscribe is enabled, the asterisk (*) becomes a *special/reserved* character.
- You must use the dot (.) to delimit each level
- You can have up to 3 levels: `a.b.c`
- You can only use the wildcard (*) at the end: `a.b.*`, not `a.*.c`

You have already visited our [JS wildcard subscribe docs](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#subscribe_example_wildcard), but for anyone new to this, [visit our developers page](http://www.pubnub.com/developers) and choose the SDK (over 70 SDKs) you are using for more details.

[See Wildcard Subscribe in the PubNub Knowledge Base](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/wildcard-subscribe) for more details.

Please confirm that this has resolved your questions.

Comment: Just prior to asking this question, I had contacted the support email, and their response, after the comments above, was that the "docs are ahead of engineering" and that it would be a enabled the day after, and it was. Thanks for the responses!